# Elasticsearch must_not is ignored on production environment

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch query where certain products with stock_code L1 need to be excluded.

When I try this query it doesn't exclude the articles

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [],
        "must_not": [{
            "term": {
                "stock_code": {
                    "value": "L1"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I tried different variants like these

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [],
        "must_not": [],
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must_not": [{
                    "term": {
                        "stock_code": {
                            "value": "L1"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "bool": {
                "must_not": [{
                    "term": {
                        "stock_code": {
                            "value": "L1"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }],
        "must_not": []
    }
}
```

We use elasticsearch 7.16.2

Below the mapping for the index of the products

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 3,
            "number_of_replicas": 2
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                ....
                "stock_code": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Locally on my laptop all 3 of these variants work, but on our stage and production server they don't.
Stage and Production are the same server but with different indexes

Comment: remove must from your first query use it like this 
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"stock_code":{"value":"L1"}}}]}}}

Comment: Are you sure in production you have the matching data in index?

Comment: @Amit Yes it is the same data

Comment: @AriaShahdadi i tried it and it's the same as the others, works locally but not on stage/production. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: is index mapping is from local or production ? Also, can you please try with match query insted of term and see if you are getting result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer, my apologies. Turns on along the way the index was changed without by someone. changing to a new index and reseeding fixed this